# shrink wrap not move well when rotating the rigging bone

Tags: modeling, rigging, objects, armature, shrinkwrap

How do I fix the shrink wrap on an object that does not follow the object when I rotate the rigging bone, the object (ball) and the shrink wrap already parent together with the bone.[image] bone.

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/